# Is there a way to start a Rails puma webserver within rails without a db connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I have a microservice that is taking in webhooks to process but it is currently getting pounded by the sender of said webhooks. Right now I am taking them and inserting the webhooks into the db for processing but the data is so bursty at times that I don't have enough bandwidth to manage the flood of requests and I cannot scale anymore as I'm out of db connections. The current thought is to just take the webhooks and throw them into a Kafka queue for processing; using Kafka I can scale up the number of frontend workers to whatever I need to handle the deluge of requests and I have the replayability of Kafka. By throwing the webhooks into Kafka, the frontend web server no longer needs a pool of db connections as it literally is just taking the request and throwing into the queue for processing. Does anyone have any knowledge on removing the db connectivity from Puma or have an alternative to do what's being asked?

Currently running
ruby 2.6.3
rails 6.0.1
puma 3.11

Comment: looks like gem https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-nulldb-adapter may be useful for you

Comment: The **what** adapter? Nulldb? You are my hero @x'ES that's exactly what I needed. I don't really care about database connection, and I thought I disabled activerecord altogether, but some things still asking about database.yml. Let them eat nulldb!

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using Puma's before fork and on_worker_boot methods to not re-establish the database connection for those particular web workers within the config